# Plot multiple figures from dictionary

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a dictionary that has stored monthly temperature data for 10 years for 20+ lat,lon locations. I want to loop through this dictionary and plot 20+ different line plots. Here I have provided where the data comes from (a netcdf file), sliced a single decade in time, and then outputted the dictionary entry value.

```
data=xr.open_dataset('E:/Riskpulse_HD/Jon climate study/adaptor.mars.internal-1583855532.1432714-8122-5-ace27afd-90c0-4a7d-b9ca-f3d5528c5ea1.nc')    
time = data['time']
start_date1 = dt.datetime(1990,1,1)
end_date1 = dt.datetime(1999,12,31)
times1=time.sel(time=slice(start_date1,end_date1))
cities['Shanghai']['1990s']

<xarray.DataArray 't2m' (time: 120)>
array([13.714203 , 13.964508 , 15.832062 , 19.553162 , 21.987793 ,
       25.075317 , 26.624298 , 26.381012 , 24.993042 , 23.088745 ,...
```

Now I try to set up a loop to loop through all of the keys in the dictionary where the only thing that changes in the name of the city.

```
for i in len(cities.keys()):
    plt.plot(times1['time'],cities[i]['1990s'])
```

Ideally I would get out 20+ different line plots corresponding to all the cities in the dictionary, but I get this error.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you also show an example of your time data? And preferably include the full stack trace.

Comment: Please provide a full code. What is cities[i]? How do you expect a dict to work with integer indices? Why not use ``for city in cities``?

Comment: Please next time better provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the len() function to get the size of the dictionary (which will be an integer) and iterate over it which is not possible.
I think this is what you are wanting to do:

```
for i in cities.keys():
    plt.plot(times1['time'],cities[i]['1990s'])
```